# How do I override an association (by using a Factory) when using FactoryGirls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

In my app, I have a `User` model that `has_one` `Profile` model. Then I have a `Service` model that `belongs_to` a `User`.

I'm trying to use FactoryGirl to create a `Profile` that is different from the default, then associate a `User` (created via FactoryGirl) to that `Profile`, and finally associate that `User` to a `Service`.

```
@profile_first_name = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, first_name: "UniqueFirstName")

@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, profile: @profile_first_name)
```

Checking with debugger, at this point everything seems to work. The User has the right first_name:

```
[#<Profile id: 1, user_id: 1, first_name: "UniqueFirstName", ...
```

But then I run the code to create a Service and associate this custom User, @user, to the Service:

```
@service = FactoryGirl.create(:service, name: "Tester Service", user: @user)
```

Again, checking with debugger and querying the database, this service SHOULD be associated with a user with first_name = 'UniqueFirstName'. Instead, it has the default profile (presumably because it is using the default User factory):

```
#<Profile id: 2, user_id: 1, first_name: "John" ...
```

I need to know how I have can create factories by overriding attributes, then use those factories within other factories (in general for any kind of relationship). What am I missing here?

Just FYI, here are my Factories:

```
#factories/profile.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    first_name  "John"
    last_name   "Doe"
    shop_name   "Casual"
    name_layout "name"
    country     "US"
    city        "Boston"
    about <<-EOF
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
      ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
      in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum.
    EOF
  end
end


#factories/user.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "user+#{n}@example.com" }
    password 'testtest'
    password_confirmation 'testtest'

    after(:build) do |user|
      user.profile = FactoryGirl.build(:profile, user: user)
    end
  end
...
end
```

Things I've tried: 
Manually setting the profile of the user of the service:

```
@service = FactoryGirl.create(:service, name: "Globe Tester", user: @maker1)
@service.user.profile = @profile_first_name
```

That didn't work either.

Comment: Can you please also post the code for the service factory?

Answer (score 0):

why does your profile id=2 in your second example? It looks like you are creating two profiles.

Honestly, I usally set it via the id rather than the associated model and have not had that problem (like profile_id rather than profile). Also you might want to check the dirty? value of the objects.